# Android Studio: Bad JNI version passed in linked C++ library

Tags: android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to use a C++ library with Java bindings inside an Android Studio project. I have linked the CMakeLists.txt as an external C++ Project and it builds with zero errors and the libraries appear under the cpp folder inside my application. The library is located in `/MyApplication/app/dnp3/`[image]

When I try to run it on a Galaxy S7 by calling the library using `static{System.loadLibrary("opendnp3java")}` inside a JAVA file, I get the following error related to JNI. I can load any of the other libraries without getting a crash

```
07-10 13:02:54.019 2738-2738/com.company.MyApplication E/art: Bad JNI version passed to GetEnv: 65544

    --------- beginning of crash
07-10 13:02:54.020 2738-2738/com.company.MyApplication A/libc: /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/dnp3/java/cpp/adapters/JNI.cpp:43: static JNIEnv *JNI::GetEnv(): assertion "env" failed
    Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2738 (rols.MyApplication)
```

This is the function inside JNI.cpp that causes the crash

```
JNIEnv* JNI::GetEnv()
{
    JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
    vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, OPENDNP3_JNI_VERSION);
    assert(env);         // This line casues the error
    return env;
}
```

`OPENDNP3_JNI_VERSION` is defined in JNI.h as the following

```
#define OPENDNP3_JNI_VERSION JNI_VERSION_1_8
```

This is my `build.gradle` file. I had to hardcode the JAVA paths as Android Studio CMake cannot find JNI without it and throws an error caused by not finding JNI. (CMake outside of Android Studio has no problem finding JNI)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        publishNonDefault true
        applicationId "com.comapny.MyApplication"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a",
                        "-DJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64",
                        //"-DJAVA_DIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/",
                        "-DJAVA_AWT_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so",
                        "-DJAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so",
                        //"-DJAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include",
                        "-DJAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux",
                        "-DJAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include",
                        "-DDNP3_JAVA=ON"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'dnp3/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

CMake has the following output when building the project

```
External native generate JSON release: building json with force flag false
External native generate JSON release: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 24 for ABI ARM64_V8A and min SDK version 24
External native generate JSON release: rebuilding JSON /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a/android_gradle_build.json due to:
External native generate JSON release: - expected json /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a/android_gradle_build.json file is not present, will remove stale json folder
External native generate JSON release: - missing previous command file /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a/cmake_build_command.txt, will remove stale json folder
External native generate JSON release: removing stale contents from '/home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a'
External native generate JSON release: created folder '/home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a'
External native generate JSON release: executing cmake Executable : /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake
arguments : 
-H/home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/dnp3
-B/home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-DANDROID_NDK=/home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja
-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a
-DJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
-DJAVA_AWT_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
-DJAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
-DJAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
-DJAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include
-DDNP3_JAVA=ON
jvmArgs : 


-- Check for working C compiler: /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake build is: Release
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (found version "1.8.0.171") found components:  Development 
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so  
ASIO has been checked out as a git submodule: /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/dnp3/deps/asio/asio/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a
External native generate JSON release: done executing cmake
External native generate JSON release: write build output /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a/cmake_build_output.txt
External native generate JSON release: write command file /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a/cmake_build_command.txt
External native generate JSON release: JSON generation completed without problems

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 9s
External native generate JSON debug: streaming 1 JSON files
External native generate JSON debug: string JSON file /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/android_gradle_build.json
External native generate JSON release: streaming 1 JSON files
External native generate JSON release: string JSON file /home/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/arm64-v8a/android_gradle_build.json
```

AS you can see from this output, CMake is able to find JNI under `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so`, so I am not sure why I get an error related to passing a bad JNI version. The bindings also require Java 1.8 or greater

I am running on virtual Ubuntu machine

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Any help or ideas is appreciated.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The Java library bindings of the C++ project is Maven based and requires the following inside the projects pom.xml  file. So, I put it inside the dependencies of the build.gradle.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.automatak.dnp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>opendnp3-bindings</artifactId>
    <version>${opendnp3.version}</version>
</dependency>


dependencies {
    . . .
    compile "com.automatak.dnp3:opendnp3-bindings:${opendnp3.version}"
}
```

But this throws the following error

```
Could not get unknown property 'opendnp3' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

**EDIT 2**

I redefined OPENDNP3_JNI_VERSION

```
#define OPENDNP3_JNI_VERSION JNI_VERSION_1_6
```

And it throws [this error](https://www.pastebucket.com/566760) when trying to run on the project

Comment: The example code shows the version parameter used as `JNI_VERSION_1_6` maybe Android does not support later versions see: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni    Note the the JNI version is not the same as the Java version

Comment: @RichardCritten CrittenHow would I go about setting the JNI to 1_6? I made an edit with a new Error output caused when trying to define OPENDNP3_JNI_VERSION as JNI_VERSION_1_6. Do I have to install another version of JNI?